# CRM with webmail integrated

Tags: php, crm, mailgun, webmail

I'm building a CRM in PHP to a customer.
One thing that the customer asked me if it's possible is the chance to manage his emails inside the CRM, without leaving the CRM to a webmail for instance. Not only to send emails (that's easy) but also to fetch inbox, see other email folders like Spam, Drafts, Sent items and even create email accounts (and other Admin features). It's really like a webmail, but without leaving the CRM. So, I don't want to build a webmail when there are already good Webmail out there. And I don't want to build something hard to maintain.
What are my options? Are there webmails that you can integrate? Do you suggest something like "mailgun"?
We're using a Windows host with Plesk, but I think we could change if necessary.

Thank you!

Comment: _"What are my options?"_ Convince your customer that this is a bad idea. The pain and annoyance of maintaining your own email server isn't remotely worth it. Just pay for a hosting service, it'll be significantly cheaper, more reliable, and more feature-rich than anything you'll implement yourself.

Comment: @AlexHowansky, in my question I said that we have an hosting already and we are paying for it. We have an email server. My question is related to fetch emails with PHP. Instead of leaving the CRM to enter a Webmail the customer wants to see emails directly inside the CRM.

Comment: I understand. My comment still applies. You could spend a year building a custom solution and it won't be as good as, as cheap as, as reliable as, say, simply hosting email at Google and using their tools. Email hosting is a solved problem, it's virtually never beneficial to do it yourself. "I don't want to leave the CRM to manage email" is not a reasonable justification to do all those things yourself.

Comment: @AlexHowansky, I agree with you, there are already great tools to manage emails. In this case though, we don't want to force users to manage emails inside CRM, only give them that chance if they want to. And this would always be a simpler version of a webmail, minimal version I would say. Only to see inbox emails and reply to them. And send emails ofc. But giving the chance to login to a professional webmail.

Or, and please help me on this, use a Webmail that could be integrated inside CRM. Not an iframe, maybe a single sign-on solution or something like that. Is there anything like that?